# Firebase: duplicate notifications on single device

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase for push notification. Sometimes I am getting duplicate notifications on a single device even though I have passed only one firebase token in the post request from my java code.
Can anyone help me to avoid duplication of notification?

Comment: Can you post code/configuration that you have?

Comment: I believe the FCM/GCM documentation states that you may receive duplicates sometimes. You will have to work around it in your client.

Comment: are you using the topics API or the send to Token api ?
in any case you can contact firebase support and report the message id.